# gcloud components update fails with UnicodeDecodeError in MacOS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

gcloud components update fails with UnicodeDecodeError in MacOS. Its not clear what would be causing this issue in MacOS and it says Hotfix for UnicodeDecodeError issue affecting logging. How do I get past this issue?

This is my current configuration

```
gcloud -v
Google Cloud SDK 190.0.0
beta 2017.09.15
bq 2.0.29
core 2018.02.16
gsutil 4.28
Updates are available for some Cloud SDK components.  To install them,
please run:
  $ gcloud components update
```

This is the error I get

```
  Container Engine
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 859, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 732, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 474, in format
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file log.py, line 184
      ▪ Added container/use_v1_api_client property as an alias of
        container/use_v1_api. container/use_v1_api is still supported.

  Kubernetes Engine
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 859, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 732, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 474, in format
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file log.py, line 184
      ▪ Added --enable-pod-security-policy flag to enable PodSecurityPolicy
        enforcement in clusters: gcloud <alpha|beta> container clusters
        <create|update> --enable-pod-security-policy

  Stackdriver Debugger
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 859, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 732, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 474, in format
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file log.py, line 184
      ▪ Changed gcloud beta source upload command to use the .gcloudignore
        file if present. If not present and .gitignore is, .gitignore will
        still be used. See gcloud topic gcloudignore to learn more.

190.0.1 (2018-02-22)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 859, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 732, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 474, in format
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file log.py, line 184
      ▪ Hotfix for UnicodeDecodeError issue affecting logging.
```

Comment: Is your SDK updated, please check

Comment: I am able to update components `gcloud -v, 
Google Cloud SDK 197.0.0` make sure you have the latest version `197.0.0`

Comment: I just posted my current configuration and the error which I get when I update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can see your Python version is Ok (2.7).
You may need to run `gcloud init` before trying to update.

If the issue persists or you already ran the aforementioned command, it would be faster to [reinstall gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-macos). [Current version was released today](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#19800_2018-04-18) (198.0.0).

Comment: reinstall helped finally